# Different autocomplete function and parameter whether a checkbox is checked or not

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Right know I'm using two different input-fields, which are connected with a autocomplete-function (Jquery UI).

**First:**

```
$( "#field_1" ).autocomplete({
    source: "script_1.php",
    minLength: 3,
    autoFocus: true,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        // Do something
    },
    search: function (event, ui) { anything_a(); },
    open: function (event, ui) { anything_b(); },
    close: function (event, ui) { anything_c(); }
});
```

**Second:**

```
$( "#field_2" ).autocomplete({
    source: "script_2.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        // Do something different
    },
    open: function(event, ui) { anything(); }
});
```

But I need to use just one input field and a checkbox.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="just_one_field">
<input type="checkbox" id="autocomplete_checkbox">
```

If the checkbox is unchecked while typing the first script with it's parameter will be used. If the checkbox is checked, the second one should be used.

**JS:**

```
$( "#just_one_field" ).autocomplete({
    source: function() {
        if ($('#autocomplete_checkbox').is(':checked')) return 'script_1.php';
        else return 'script_2.php';
    }
});
```

My attempt doesn't work. I think the syntax is wrong...

How do I have to combine those autocomplete()-function with the parameters to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the function in `source` wrongly. [Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

```
$( "#just_one_field" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(req, resp) {
        $.ajax({
           type: 'get',
           url: ($('#autocomplete_checkbox').is(':checked') ? 'script_1.php' : 'script_2.php' ) //choose url based on checkbox
                  + '?term=' + req.term, //add "term" parameter and insert the "term" from req parameter
           success: function(data) {
               resp(data);//call resp callback with the data you got from the server
           }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the checkbox is checked or not by

```
var auto1 = $('field').autocomplete(options 1);
var auto2 = $('field').autocomplete(options 2);
var aactive;
auto1.disable();
auto2.disable();

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#checkbox').click(function{
changeAutocomplete();
});

});

function changeAutocomplete(){
if($('#checkbox').attr('checked')=='checked'){
     active = auto1;
    }else{
     active = auto2;
    }
active.enable();
}
```

Comment: `auto1.disable();` leads to `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`